# How can i convert d3 force directive graph to use with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, d3.js

I have created a D3 force directive graph with normal javascript.

Here is the [**working D3 graph**](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/u5k4jcw2/)

Now i need to get the data from a service and generate the graph in AngularJS. How can I make a directive out of this? Any example or guidance will be great.

I have made a controller to get the data from the service. And the code is here:

```
 $scope.buildchart = function(widget) {
        var w2 = new Worker("scripts/webworkers/bigQueryWorker.js");           
        w2.postMessage($scope.selectedClass + "," 
          + $rootScope.hierarchystring.toString() 
          + "," + "Hierarchy" + "," + Digin_Engine_API);

        w2.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            hierarchyRetrieved(event);
        });

        function hierarchyRetrieved(event) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log("Hierarchy data is");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

        };
    };
```

Is there a way I could get this data inside this function?

```
function loadImage() {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have put is a little heavy for me to angularize but I ll try to illustrate your case with some snippets :)

First create a DOM where you want to inject your angular directive which will make the d3 chart.

That's done like this:

```
<svg linear-chart></svg>
```

Here linear-chart will trigger the directive.
So lets see a directive:

```
app.directive('linearChart', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',

        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        //all your code for making the force layout
}});
```

Next challenge the data is pulled via async task done by web worker.

```
$scope.buildchart = function(widget) {
        var w2 = new Worker("scripts/webworkers/bigQueryWorker.js");           
        w2.postMessage($scope.selectedClass + "," + $rootScope.hierarchystring.toString() + "," + "Hierarchy" + "," + Digin_Engine_API);
        w2.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            hierarchyRetrieved(event);
        });

        function hierarchyRetrieved(event) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(event.data);
            $scope.data = obj;//setting the data into the scope object.

        };
    };
```

So now whenever your async task completes the scope data is set to that.
We know that the value inside the scope data changes so we need to have a watch function which will trigger the link function on change of the `$scope.data`

Something like this

```
app.directive('linearChart', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',

        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            //this will watch the scope data
            scope.$watch(
                "data",function(){/*your d3 code for making the forcelayout which will get triggred when scope.data changes :)
*/})...
```

Here is a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/yar5sco6/3/)

**Note:** Here i am mocking your webworker code by a button click in the `loadData` function.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks cyril! Great help indeed

Comment: Cyril can you help me with this? when i generate the directive inside a dialog box, it does not work. here is the plunker code http://plnkr.co/edit/n15aFqOK7uZSDCVpQ9lz?p=preview

Comment: One small thing d3.select("#d3ForceNew") is incorrect 
1) There is no such div
2) you are appending an svg 
3) you already have an svg
so it should be this
 var svg = d3.select("svg").attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height);
http://plnkr.co/edit/EggzAyllnIpmNO5KTPhg?p=preview

Comment: Thanks again! one more problem, when i click a node, mouse gets attached to the node and it cant be released when it is inside a modal.  do you suggest any solution for that?

Comment: if you see this http://plnkr.co/edit/3mpEVJdj11RQPcFM6oyB?p=preview i have disabled the node drag...so now on dragging of node the dialog is moving. I think that is the reason why on drag its sticking. the material design dilog drag and node drag are conflicting.

Comment: how can i load the graph with one node initially?

Comment: simple set a single node initially: `$scope.data = {
            "name": "flare", children:[]}` then later on click load the full data the watch function will update the graph whenever there is change in the scope data.

Comment: what i actually want is to load the full data and show only the first node, so that user can click and expand. currently the graph is too big

Comment: like i said you just need to update the data set it will reflect automatically in svg coz of the watch function.

Comment: is not there a event for each node to collapse and expand? because each time i might have to make a service call to apply the data. or if i can show only top two levels initially, it would be fine

Comment: There is a click/dblclick event available on node.