# How to restrict number of nodes initially in d3 Force directed graph

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, d3-force-directed

This could be another question on improvement, i have made a directive with the help of [`Existing question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610755/how-can-i-convert-d3-force-directive-graph-to-use-with-angularjs), which is working well.

now when the user creates this chart dynamically, when the data load exceeds, the browser becomes heavy and user interface gets stuck.

how do i restrict the nodes level to be 2 , when the chart is loaded initially.
i tried to make a service call one by one, but that does not work.

**Here is the code:**

```
 function click(d) {
                    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
                    if (d.children) {
                        d._children = d.children;
                        d.children = null;
                    } else {
                        d.children = d._children;
                        d._children = null;
                    }
                    update();
                }
```

**[`Application with Data`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/yar5sco6/5/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this will help out. From this example : [How can I start with all the nodes collapsed in d3js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647653/how-can-i-start-with-all-the-nodes-collapsed-in-d3js)

I edited your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/yar5sco6/7/

I removed the original call to `update()`. So you have to press `Load` then `Start`.

This collapses all nodes. From there you can open up the first two hierarchies fairly easy :)

This is the main implementation :

//HTML

```
<button id='startForce'>START</button>
```

//JS

```
document.getElementById('startForce').addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log('start');

            var nodes = flatten(root);
            nodes.forEach(function(d) {
              d._children = d.children;
              d.children = null;
            });
            update();
          })
```

Comment: Im confused as to what you mean by create it dynamically. Do you just mean inserting a bunch of data ? So you want it to only show the top parent and the first level of children ?

Comment: nice! this is what i want! but cant this be done when loading the initial time itself without adding another click event?

Comment: Of course : http://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/yar5sco6/8/ Just removed the button and event listener and created a function startVis() which gets called straight away (after you click the load button)

Comment: No problem there's plenty of examples around for simulating node click so use one of them if you dont want all the nodes closed and show one set of children